# How can I repair windows xp when it prompts me to respond and all usb devices are disabled?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, repair

I have a computer on which I am trying to do an XP repair. However, the repair "prompts" me with a Window about XP compatibility drivers. The problem is that XP Repair disables the USB devices that I need to use in order to answer the question. There are no ps2 connections on this box or I would use them. I don't care if the drivers are installed or not, I just want a chance to answer the prompt so the Repair will continue. It is hung waiting for my response.

Is there a way to auto-respond to every prompt during the repair? Or is there a way to keep XP Repair from disabling the USB devices? I can handle every other single problem with this install if I can get past the "prompt" issue with no USB access.

Comment: Not that I know of, why are you repairing it?

Comment: what's the exact error message?

Comment: if you have no ps2 connectors or usb, then surely getting past any prompt is going to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

this link may help regarding automating your windows installation.. called unattended windows installation http://unattended.msfn.org/unattended.xp/